# Bouncing ball-like animation to draw attention towards a button

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I already checked various tutorials and information but cannot put together the last mile.

My code is

```swift
struct WelcomeView: View {
    @State private var chevronAnimationRunning = true

    var body: some View {

        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            .offset(y: chevronAnimationRunning ? 0 : 20)
            .animation(
                Animation
                    .interpolatingSpring(
                        stiffness: 350,
                        damping: 15,
                        initialVelocity: 20)
                    .repeatForever(
                        autoreverses: true),
                value: chevronAnimationRunning)
            .onAppear {
                chevronAnimationRunning.toggle()
            }

    }
}
```

The idea is that the downwards-pointing chevron icon should draw the attention to a "create" button, by always kinda "hopping".

The `interpolatingSpring` animation basically does the trick by modifying the `.offset(y)` attribute; the problem is that it doesn't "reset". I think it should "start again" from the initial offset value, but I am not able to accomplish this.
The code posted above is already the "second" variant, I initially tried without the helper state variable `chevronAnimationRunning` being involved.

Thanks for your help y'all!

Comment: So close! If you want it to "reset" to it's starting "un-hopped" position each time, just change the `autoreverses` argument in `.repeatForever` to false. If this is set to true, it will reset but it'll animate to the reset.

Comment: thanks @Stoic but I tried that as well. The chevron is still just frozen at the place. You can basically say it doesn't make a difference whether it's true or false…

Comment: ok @Stoic nevermind there was something weird in my preview. When I wrapped all this into a VStack for example it worked nicely. Thank you so much! Care to provide this as an answer that I can mark as accepted?
Oh and btw.: is there a way to have this without the `private var chevronAnimationRunning` being involved? I don't like the necessity to maintain a global state for such a purpose…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `autoreverses:`  parameter of the `.repeatForever` modifier dictates whether the animation will animate back to its beginning state or if it will simply "reset" without animating back.

By setting it to be `false` the animation will reset instead of animating back, and it will look more like an arrow pointing a certain direction rather than just bouncing back and forth.

```
.repeatForever(
    autoreverses: false),          // HERE
    value: chevronAnimationRunning
)
```

As for your comment, you just need a shared value that `.offset` and `.animation` can each access. So, if you didn't want your `WelcomeView` to know about `.chevronAnimationRunning`, you could create your own separate view modifier struct and mix `.offset` and `.animation` in there.

Comment: I know the first part didn't end up being what you were asking because you just had a preview problem but I thought it might be relevant 